# apoc.export.csv.query runs without completing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to execute a csv export using the APOC procedure library, specifically, the procedure CALL apoc.export.csv.query

The procedure runs forever even with a simple query, for example:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix' return m.name","results.csv",{})
```

The Neo4j version is 3.2.1 and the corresponding APOC version is apoc-3.2.0.3.

Is this a bug or syntax error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the query from the browser that may indeed be a **visualization bug** (browser unable to show you the result of the procedure ... which does actually finish in fact). You do get the result in the file though, correct ? Try the same command-line with the cypher-shell and you should get a result immediately.

I have logged an issue for something similar to that but I haven't checked yet if it has been resolved in 3.2.2.

Hope this helps,
Regards,
Tom

Comment: The file is being created successfully on disk, so it is a problem with the browser visualization.